# What are all options to execute and source a bash file? Why shebang is not checked?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash file and I see that I can do on it the following:

```
./file.sh               >> executes the file following the chmod -x file.sh rule
bash ./file.sh          >> executes the file 
bash file.sh            >> executes the file 
source ./file.sh        >> source the file code
file                    >> source the file code
```

Am I correct in the interpretation or wrong? I hear that there is something "PATH" related, but I don't know about.

Also, as far as I am seeing the shebang/hashbang is not always checked. Why not? This is an example I am using:
`#!/bin/echo "This script should be sourced in a shell"`

Any insights would be good; as I am few weeks old to bash.

Comment: The last one looks wrong. It does not source `file`. It looks for `file` in one of the `$PATH` directories and will attempt to execute it if found.

Comment: Got it. I did not know that. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The `#!` only applies to the first and last cases. The others either explicitly or implicitly provide an interpreter to use on the command line and do not use the one provided by `#!`.

Comment: The last one is wrong. `file` is a simple command in that context and is searched in this order: If shell is interactive and name (`file`) is an alias it is replaced by the text of the alias. If name is a shell function it is called. Otherwise, if name is a builtin command it is handled by the shell itself without creating a new process. Otherwise, if name contains no slashes, shell searches each element of `$PATH` (in order, from left to right) for a directory containing an executable file by that name and execute it if it is found.

Comment: @user3053247 : To add to this, actually _file_ is a standard command and should be in your PATH. To learn more about it, do a `man file`.

Comment: @user3053247 You missed in your list the variations `source file.sh` and  `. file.sh`. To learn about the difference to your `source ./file.sh`, see the section _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_ in the bash man-page.

Comment: @user3053247 : I took the liberty to remove the _zsh_ tag from your question, since there is nothing related to zsh in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is a bit off:

```
./file.sh               >> executes the file with its requested interpreter
bash ./file.sh          >> executes the file with bash, no matter which language it is
bash file.sh            >> executes the file with bash, no matter which language it is
source ./file.sh        >> sources the code in the current shell
file                    >> executes the file from PATH with its requested interpreter
```

By default you should always use `./file.sh` (if it's in the current directory) or `file` (if it's renamed and put in a directory in PATH), since that way it can be a Python script or Ruby script or C binary and it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. Does the #! in the header play any role in these cases?

Comment: @user3053247 The `#!` is how the script specifies an interpreter, so it plays a role in the two cases mentioned where it uses its requested interpreter. Otherwise, it's a comment that doesn't affect anything

Comment: The plain `file` (in the last case) won't be searched through the directories in `PATH` if it is an alias (for interactive shell only) or a shell function or a shell builtin.